# Is there an Docker Maven Plugin in jar file?

Tags: maven, docker, jar, maven-plugin

Just a quick inquiry to see if there are any .jar files for docker - maven plugin that can be directly installed in Apache Maven using the mvn install command.

I was trying to run a docker-maven plugin using a pom file on windows but was getting the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to parse plugin descriptor for
>   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compone nt-metadata:1.6
>   (C:\Users\user2.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-com
>   ponent-metadata\1.6\plexus-component-metadata-1.6.jar): error in
>   opening zip file -> [Help 1]

I have installed plexus-component-metadata-1.6.jar and plexus-component-metadata-1.6.pom but it is not working..

Any help please..??

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when your connection gets **interrupted** during your dependencies are being downloaded **last time**.

**Delete** the relevant repository **folder** and run `mvn clean install` command **again** to download a fresh copy of **corrupted** file.